# How to refund a transaction in authorized.net using php

Tags: php, authorize.net

I want to refund a transition using CIM .I have created customer in authorized.net and make transition using the customer profile id and payment profile id.Now i want to refund a transition but i have only 
1-customer profile id 
2-customer payment profile id
3-transition id
So i try to use the **Refund a Transaction** sample code provided by authorized net but it require the CardNumber which i have not 
Authorized.net gives the card number in mask format 
So How can i refund a transition 
Can anyone help me I am thankfull 
Waiting for your response

Answer (score 3):

If the transaction has settled, you can [create a refund transaction](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-refund-a-transaction) using the original transactionID and last 4 of the card number.  If you don't have the last 4 stored in your system, use [getTransactionDetailsRequest](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-details) and use the data from the <payment> object.